# concatMap explanation

Tags: haskell

Hello people of StackOverflow!

I've started working with Haskell, and have stumbled upon the `concatMap` function.
Since I'm quite new to this language, I have some problems understanding the following code ([source](http://wiki.cs.pdx.edu/forge/concatmap.html)):

```
concatMap f = cmap where
    cmap [] = []
    cmap (x : xs) = accum (f x) where
        accum [] = cmap xs
        accum (y : ys) = y : accum ys
```

As far as I understand the function `concatMap` takes in an argument `f` which is a function.

But how can we set a function equal to another one? Are we setting the result of `f` equal to `cmap`, or are we using `cmap` as a parameter for `f`?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That code is written point-free-ish, which isn't very beginner friendly. Add `ys` on both sides of `=` and it might get easier, e.g. `concatMap f ys = cmap ys`. Also, the canonical definition of `concatMap f` is `concat . map f`.

Comment: I'd probably go a bit further and say the code is confusing. I don't see any good reason to write the weird `accum` function instead of just using `cmap (x : xs) = f x ++ cmap xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted is not terribly easy for a beginner. Fortunately, we can rewrite it piece by piece:

```
accum [] = cmap xs
accum (y : ys) = y : accum ys
```

The function above, when the input list is empty returns `cmap xs`, otherwise on `y:ys` emits `y` as the first output element and then proceeds to output `accum xs`, recursively.

Hence, `accum zs` will simply output all the elements in `zs` and then, after that, continue with `cmap xs`. We can rewrite that as:

```
accum zs = zs ++ cmap xs
```

where `++` is list concatenation.

We can then rewrite the whole code as follows, accordingly:

```
concatMap f = cmap where
    cmap [] = []
    cmap (x : xs) = f x ++ cmap xs
```

We can further rewrite is as

```
concatMap f [] = []
concatMap f (x : xs) = f x ++ concatMap f xs
```

which should be more accessible for a beginner. More informally the above definition satisfies the equation:

```
concatMap f [x1,x2,...,xn] =
   f x1 ++ f x2 ++ ... ++ f xn ++ []
```

So, we can see what `concatMap` does. It applies `f` to every list element, and for every list element `f` must return a list. Then, all such lists are concatenated.

For example:

```
concatMap (\x -> [1..x]) [3,1,2] =
   [1,2,3] ++ [1] ++ [1,2] =
   [1,2,3,1,1,2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick but very detailed answer @chi
I have marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

chi's answer covers how `concatMap` works, so I will focus specifically on one of your doubts:

> But how can we set a function equal to another one?

A function in Haskell is a value, just like any other.

```
GHCi> foo = "foo"
```

This is a definition of `foo`, which happens to be a string:

```
GHCi> :t foo
foo :: [Char]
GHCi> putStrLn foo
foo
```

In the same way...

```
GHCi> add = (+)
```

... this is a definition of `add`, which happens to be a function:

```
GHCi> :t add
add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
GHCi> add 2 3
5
```

In the definition above, in order to emphasise that I was just defining a value, I didn't write either of the parameters of `add` explicitly. It is perfectly fine to do that, though:

```
GHCi> add x y = (+) x y
```

(Note that `x + y`, which is how we usually would write the right-hand side of the definition above, is simply convenient alternative syntax for `(+) x y`.)

A different way of writing the definition takes advantage of *partial application* to mention only the first parameter:

```
GHCi> add x = (+) x
```

We also can, just for the sake of it (and to perhaps clarify what is going on), move the `(+) x` to a separate definition in a where-clause...

```
GHCi> :{
GHCi| add x = plusX
GHCi|     where
GHCi|     plusX = (+) x
GHCi| :}
```

... and write the second parameter explicitly again:

```
GHCi> :{
GHCi| add x = plusX
GHCi|     where
GHCi|     plusX y = (+) x y
GHCi| :}
```

`plusX` is a function which takes an argument and add it to `x`. `add` is a function which takes an argument, `x`, and gives back the `plusX` function corresponding to that `x`. It is this second function that takes the second argument to `add` when we do `add 2 3` (which, by the way, is equivalent to `(add 2) 3`).

Now, compare the above with your `concatMap` definition:

```
concatMap f = cmap where
    cmap [] = []
    cmap (x : xs) = accum (f x) where
        accum [] = cmap xs
        accum (y : ys) = y : accum ys
```

The definitions are laid out in an analogous way. `cmap` is a function that takes a list and uses `f`, the argument to `concatMap`, to produce a result from it, much in the same way `plusX` used the `x` argument of `add`.

So, to sum it up:

> Are we setting the result of f equal to cmap, or are we using cmap as a parameter for f?

Neither. We are using `f` to define `cmap`, which is then used to define `concatMap` as a whole.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @duplode.
I had to choose between chi's and your answer to mark as "The answer". For me, I needed both yours and chi's answer to fully understand what was going on. But I marked Chi's answer, because it gives a broader overview of the functions of concatMap, which might be useful for others, seeking help in this matter.
But I appriciate your effort, it helped me a lot !